# Sosumi increase disk storage

Tags: macosx

I installed Macos successfully using sosumi on ubuntu 20.10 but unable to install XCODE due insufficient storage. How can I increase mu disk space.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd snap/sosumi/common
qemu-img resize macos.qcow2 +20G
```

Unfortunately, this must be done **before** macOS installation. Make shure qemu-utils are installed. Modify +**20**G as required in Gigabyte

[Source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QWZ_LjzT39k&t=130s)